# Repeated Measures ANOVA Tests of Within-Subjects Contrasts

Tags: t-test, repeated-measures, spss, contrasts, f-test

Using the MIXED procedure and a set of repeated measures data of vertical format, I obtained the results of fixed effect estimates and related t-tests for orthogonal polynomial linear and quadratic contrasts. If the comparison of t-test results with F-tests for the same contrasts obtained from repeated measures ANOVA analysis is desired, What syntax and/or menu command should be used?

Comment: I assume by "mixed procedure" your using SAS? If so its best to explicitly say so and use tag.

Comment: I meant MIXED command IBM SPSS commonly used for linear mixed models.

Comment: I would specify your software in your question and apply a tag.